# Performance: Slicing and reversing Numpy arrays efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, slice

I want to calculate 10 crops of images: the top-left corner, top-right corner, bottom-left corner, bottom-right corner, center, and all of them mirrored. The images are stored in the Numpy array `blob` with the shape `N x Channels x Height x Width`, where `N` is the number of source images.

The slices' top-left points are stored in `tls`, the slices' bottom-right points are stored in `brs`. The following code extracts the crops as well as the horizontally mirrored versions of each crop:

```
m = 10 if mirror else 5
crops_shape = ((blob.shape[0] * m,) + blob.shape[1:-2] + crop_dimensions)
crops = np.empty(shape=crops_shape, dtype=blob.dtype)

for i in range(0, blob.shape[0]):
    p = i * m
    for k, (tl, br) in enumerate(zip(tls, brs)):
        crops[p + k] = blob[i, ..., tl[0]:br[0], tl[1]:br[1]]
    if mirror:
        crops[p + 5:p + 10] = crops[p:p + 5, ..., ::-1]

return crops
```

For a single image, `blob` could for example have the shape (1, 3, 226, 226). All the crops have the same size, for example (227x227), and thus the resulting array `crops` would in this case have the shape (10, 3, 227, 227) (when `mirror` is True).

Unfortunately the approach above is too slow (about 1.5ms / image) when `blob` is a `float32` array. Is there a way to make this faster?

Comment: Are the crops of same shapes? Could you add a sample case?

Comment: Yes, all crops have the same shape, I'm adding an example.